# Backup postgresql pg_dump - Error password

Tags: linux, postgresql

estoy armando un script en linux para realizar el respaldo de una base de datos Postgres.

Estoy utilizando el comando pg_dump, todo lindo y bello hasta que agrego la opción -W, --password por lo que he leído esta opción permite agregar la clave de acceso a la base de datos. la sentencia sería

```
pg_dump -d nameDB  -h 192.45.1.10 -p 5432 -U xuser -W 2008 >/home/pn/utils/backups/DB_nameDB.sql
```

al ejecutar presento ERROR 
" pg_dump: demasiados argumentos en la línea de órdenes (el primero es «2008») "

No se si se han topado con la misma problemática en la autenticación automática ..

Comment: Ejecuta con el -W pero sin poner el dato, a ver si te pide la contraseña

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El -W lo que hace es mostrarte el prompt para que ingreses la clave, no es que tú le puedes pasar la clave ahí, puede probar usando un '.pgpass' que creo que es el método recomendado, dicho archivo puedes colocarlo en el home del usuario que va a ejecutar el  script y el contenido del archivo seria así:
HOST:PUERTO:NOMBRE_BASE_DE_DATO:USUARIO:CLAVE

Puedes mirar la documentacion en: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/libpq-pgpass.html

Answer (score 2):

bayocr ...

Hice un script para automatizar el proceso del pgpass y del pg_dump. solo faltaría agregarlo en el cron de Linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
# backupsDB.sh
# chmod 777 backupsDB.sh
##########################


#VARIABLES DE CONEXION
localhost='192.163.5.10'
puerto='5432'
pass='2008'
user='pix'
DB='pacs'


#variable sistema
New=0
Pgpass=~/.pgpass
Dia=$(date +%Y%m%d)
Hora=$(date +%H%M%S)
Dir='/home/user/backups/'
File=DB_PACS_$Dia$Hora.sql



while [ $New -eq 0 ]; do
# verificamos si existe la carpeta de backups

if [ -d $Dir ]; then
        echo "RUTA DE RESPALDO DB "$Dir
# Verificamos si existe el archivo clave
        if [ -f $Pgpass ];then

                # metodos .SQL Linux
                        pg_dump -d $DB -h $localhost -p $puerto -U $user > $Dir/$File
                        New=1
                echo "SE GENERO EL ARCHIVO " $Dir/$File " CON EL RESPALDO DE LA BASE DE DATOS"
        else
# generamos el archivo con la clave pgpass
#host:puerto:basededatos:usuario:contraseña
# metodo linux
#echo "192.168.0.1:5432:mibase:miusuario:micontraseña" >> ~/.pgpass
metodo win
# 192.168.0.1:5432:mibase:miusuario:micontraseña > c:\documents and settings\(usuario que correrá la tarea)\datos de programa\postgresq\pgpass.conf

                echo $localhost:$puerto:$DB:$user:$pass > $Pgpass
                chmod 0600 $Pgpass
                echo " SE GENERO PARAMETRO DE ACCESO  "
        fi
else

#Creamos la carpeta de backups
        sudo mkdir $Dir
        sudo chmod 777 -R $Dir
        echo "SE CREA CARPETA DE BACKUPS"
fi
done
```